# c++ can I new a vector like this in my code into a hashmap

Tags: c++, unordered-map

```
// father is an array of integers, irrelevant to the actual question

 vector<pair<int,int>> edges = {
          {0, 2},
          {2, 3},
          {1, 4},
          {1, 5}
        };

unordered_map<int, vector<pair<int,int>> edges_map_by_component;
    for(auto edge: edges){
      if(edges_map.find(father[edge.first]) == edges_map_by_component_map.end()){
        //  ---> my question is, is the following line valid?
        edges_map_by_component.emplace(father[edge.first] , new vector<pair<int,int>>()); 
        edges_map[father[edge.first]].push_back(make_pair (edge.first,edge.second));

  }
}
```

In C++,

1. Can I add a `vector` object to the hashmap using `new` like this?
2. Is that line valid?
3. If yes, do I need to specify size for `vector`if I instantiate it
   inside the map?

Edit:
You've said I should not use `new` here, but seems like simply removing `new` is not working either. what should I do here. Basically my logic is, if the hashmap does not contain a particular key, I will create a `vector` of `pair<int, int>` for it, associate it with that key, and `push_back()` some pairs into the `vector`.

Comment: you have 'vector<pair<int,int>>' as unordered_map value. 'new' will return the pointer to vector. I am not sure if that will compile.

Comment: @TonyD what should I use instead? thanks

Comment: @BufBills: I noticed after my last comment that you had two different maps involved: you haven't shown the type of `edges_map_by_component` - perhaps it is storing pointers to vectors, and your use of `new` is in keeping.  You should really show us the declaration of `edges_map_by_component` though if you want confirmation.

Comment: you have: `edges_map`, `edges`, and `edges_map_by_component`, are they all the same variable?

Comment: @BufBills there still is `edges` in the loop and `edges_map` in the  `if` condition, what are those?

Comment: @BufBills No you didn't fix it!

Comment: @HappyCoder guess wrong @?

Comment: @iksemyonov Sorry. Fixed now! Fix for a fix, sounds like inception to me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have either a typo or a mistake in your code:

```
unordered_map<int, vector<pair<int,int>> edges_map_by_component;
//                                    ^^
```

Should be (given you're using C++11 where you don't need to put spaces between subsequent closing template braces):

```
unordered_map<int, vector<pair<int,int>>> edges_map_by_component;
//                                    ^^^
```

Other than that, indeed, remove `new`, since the second parameter of your map is `vector<pair<int, int>>`, not a pointer to that. That way it works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

int main(void)
{
    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > > mymap;
    mymap.emplace(5, std::vector<std::pair<int,int> >());
    mymap[5].push_back({5, 7});
    const std::pair<int, int> p = mymap[5].back();
    std::cout << p.first << p.second;
}
```

The types are shown explicitly for clarity sake. A shorter way to write it would be something along the lines of:

```
mymap.emplace(5, decltype(mymap)::mapped_type());
```

One more note is that the `emplace` operation uses move semantics, so there is no additional copying going on, and you can construct a `vector` beforehand, fill it with values, and pass to `emplace()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes usually. No not like you did because you are using the wrong type. What you are inserting here is a pointer to a vector which you haven't declared in your template parameters. You either need to change the template parameter to `unsorted_map<int, vector<pair<int,int> >* >` or you remove the `new`. This depends on how you want to use this structure later.